# How do I write a tab delimited text file in PHP, with proper encoding?

Tags: php, encoding

This code writes a tab delimited txt file from a database to a directory. I have a problem with the character encoding as it fails to get the non-English characters like ñ , é ,...
how can i get the encoding right? I know i should use UTF-8, but where in my code does it fit in? The characters seem ok in the db (latin1_swedish_ci) but not ok in the file.
Thanks

```
<?
     @chmod($export_txt, 0777);
    $fe = @fopen($export_txt."/export.txt", "w+");
    if($fe){           
        $somecontent = "";
        $fields_count = 0;           
        // fields headers
        $db->query($sql_view);
        if($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
            foreach($row as $key => $val){
                if($fields_count++ > 0) $somecontent .= "\t";
                $somecontent .= $key;
            }
        }
        $somecontent .= "\r\n"; 

        $db->query($sql_view);
        while($row = $db->fetchAssoc()){
            $fields_count = 0;
            foreach($row as $key => $val){
                if($fields_count++ > 0) $somecontent .= "\t";
                $somecontent .= $val;                                                                          
            }
            $somecontent .= "\r\n"; 
        }  
        // write some content to the opened file.
        if (fwrite($fe, $somecontent) == FALSE) echo 'file_writing_error'." (export.txt)"; 
        fclose($fe);           

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what encoding are your characters before calling this function, what is your source encoding?

Comment: they are picked from the database with collation latin1_swedish_ci the characters appear good in the db but when i write them to file, it does not get those non- english chars

Comment: Collation is irrelevant, but what is the charset? Collation only tells how they are sorted. If charset is latin1, it is equivalent to iso-8859-1, so translating that to UTF-8 should be ok with the method given by silentw.

Comment: not really working for txt. however, in xml i declare $somecontent = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>"; and it worked. trying it for txt

Comment: are you sure you are testing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite($fe, utf8_encode($somecontent))
```

Comment: It would be worth noting that utf8_encode translates iso-8859-1 content to utf8. It might be what OP needs, or it might not - if the source characters are in iso-8859-1, then yes.

Comment: not really working for txt. however, in xml i declare $somecontent = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>"; and it worked. trying it for txt